# Angular2 development Without node and npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am new angular2 development, and what i came to know is before starin the angular2 development, I must install the nodejs for server and npm to download dependencies from official documentation.

**I succesfully deployed the source code in tomcat sever[by build]**

So my Question is after installation and creating the new project, i got node_modules. By using these node_modules(can i start development of angular2 on another i.e a new machine where node & npm is not installed)

Basically my question is.. **I want to start development of angular2 by using the project structure on new machine. Without the installation on node & npm**

Comment: While not 100% true, it will help to think of node as the JRE. You can use node to write a webserver like Tomcat uses the JRE. But you can also use node to run a compiler like javac requires a JRE. npm is like mavin. If you fetch your libraries manually and don't use npm-build-scripts, you could do without.

Comment: Thank you @Hendrik, Somehow i did followed the plunkr approach, by downloading all the dependencies and running.

Answer (score 0):

From [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages)

> Node.js and npm are essential to Angular development.

Comment: basically nodejs will be just a server to load the angular2 app, and npm is a package to get the packages. If i have all the packages why i require npm and i will host on any other server ex.tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If you built/compiled the app and have all the modules installed (you have your node_modules) folder then its just javascript and html which you can run on any server you want.

Comment: I understood your point, But i want the development environment and then compile the code. But your speaking about after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

For npm, if you need any modules/packages, I think you can manually download the package and add it to your development environment. But what if the process needs to be automated? You can't just sit there and download all the packages from github. So npm is really helpful when it come to this. You only need a file containing all dependencies, and run it at build time (package.json)

About nodejs, nodejs allows you to run javascript on the server when you need any interaction with the database. So why don't we just go with the easy way?

Comment: Yes I too understood the same, to be more understanding and without depending on npm a sample demo app is required for me. so i am doing all this.